# jQuery affects elements one after another instead of affecting clicked element

Tags: php, jquery

I'm echoing out a number of `div` tags dynamicaly like:

```
foreach($applications as $application){
    $id =  $application->user_id;
    echo '<div class="col-md-4" id="'.$id.'">',
              '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading remove-margin">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" id="'.$id.'"> </i>
               </h4>',
         '</div>';
}
```

i want to make it so that when a user clicks the plus button in a selected div, then only that div is affected. So far when I do that, it affects the elements in sequential order, nomatter which plus I click. here's the jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fa-plus').click(function(){
                    counter = 0;
                    id      = $(this).closest('div').prop("id");
                    counter = counter+1;
                    $(this).css('color','green');
                    $('#votes-count').parent().html(counter);
                    alert(id);                  
            });

    });
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('div').prop("id");` is this code returning anything?  the closest div -> `<div class="col-md-4">` has no `id`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i edited the code for brevity, but yes it does return an alert with the id. I have edited it though.

Comment: What is `#votes-count` and its parent? can show your html markup?

Comment: where is `$id` coming from? it looks like the same for all divs, that's why it is affecting all of them

Comment: At least you can do `foreach($applications as $id=>$application)` making sure it is different for each div

Comment: or if `$id` is linked to `$application` then you should do `$application->id` instead just `$id`

Comment: You edited the question but you are still using the same `id` for all your `div` and all your `i`. The `id` should be unique per element of the DOM

Comment: The ID is being pulled out form the `foreach` as well. I just excluded that part to make it more readable. Otherwise my `foreach` looks like this `foreach($applications as $application){$id =  $application->user_id;}` etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `event` object from the `click` event to get the id of the clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fa-plus').click(function(evt){
                counter = 0;
                id      = evt.target.id;

                if($(this).attr("id") != id){
                    return;
                }

                counter = counter+1;
                $("#" + id).css('color','green');
                $('#votes-count').parent().html(counter);
                alert(id);                  
        });
});
```

You can refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for more info about the `event` object that is passed.

Answer (score 2):

You have elements with duplicated ids: `<div class="col-md-4">` and `<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>`

Please check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x618x5jp/). You need to fix the selectors with you HTML structure.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Right! The value of an ID must be unique in a web page. It is a violation of the HTML standard to use the value of an ID more than once in the same document tree.

Comment: The IDs are actually unique. They are being pulled out by the `foreach` loop, i.e they are essentialy coming from the database . Even when I view source, each div has a unique id. the problem now i guess is how to tie that ID to a click event, since its a PHP variable.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with you HTML structure. Just past some <div class="col-md-4"></div> elements

Comment: Just to be clear, you have duplicated id in your html, if your code is the one in the question. both `<div class="col-md-4" id="'.$id.'">` and `<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" id="'.$id.'">` have `id="'.$id.'"`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the same ID multiple times is not allowed. An ID is always unique. So you could do something like this with classes:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($applications as $application) {
    echo sprintf(
         '<div class="col-md-4">'
             . '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading remove-margin">'
             . '<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" data-myattr="%s"> </i>'
             . '</h4>'
             . '</div>',
         $counter++
    );
}
```

And then you could attach your click event subscriber with:

```
$(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $("i[data-myattr]")
                .click(function () {
                    counter = 0;
                    id = $(this).data("myattr");
                    $(this).css("color", "green");
                    $("#votes-count").parent().html(++counter);
                    alert(id);
                }
            );
        }
);
```

That should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate for each `fa-plus`, and bind the click on each of them.

Als access the id with *attr* instead of *prop*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fa-plus').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            counter = 0;
            id = $(this).closest('div').attr("id");
            counter = counter+1;
            $(this).css('color','green');
            $('#votes-count').parent().html(counter);
            alert(id);                  
        });
    });
});
```